# Only allow access to my Gmail account from specific country

Tags: gmail

My account has been hacked today from an EUA IP. I already changed the password, but I would like to know if I can define in Gmail a whitelist of countries from where is possible to access my account.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I read this feature on a wishlist for gmail.
I don't think something like that has been implemented yet (haven't find anything 'new' in my short research).

But you might go for the [2 Step Verification](http://www.google.com/landing/2step/) - it's pretty awesome.